# C# OrderBy leave specific element last

Tags: c#, linq

So I have an example list of Movies and I want to order them by those example Genres (Genres are string type):

```
Action
Romence
Thriller
Other
Drama
```

Now I would like to order those elements so, that it would leave `Other` as last.

```
IEnumerable<Movie> oMovies = movies.OrderBy(o => o.Genre); // need to have Other as last
```

Is it possible to do so?

**Solution**

Since Genres is String, then this solution works perfectly (credits to @PetSerAl)

```
movies.OrderBy(o => o.Genre == "Other").ThenBy(o => o.Genre)
```

Comment: Did you try assigning values to your Genres enum?

Comment: Is `Genres` `enum`, `string` or other type?

Comment: Genre is `string` type

Comment: Thank you @PetSerAl, that worked! :)

Comment: can you please add the answer at the answers section and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Have Genre with Order value:

```
Action 1
Romence 2
Thriller 3
Other 5
Drama 4
```

Then it's easy to order:

```
IEnumerable<Movie> oMovies = movies.OrderBy(o => o.Genre.Order);
```

Please note this will only work if Genre is a complex type, if it's a Enum there is another solution

Comment: There's already a much better answer in the comments (and Genre is a string I'm afraid)

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, I forgot to mention, that Genres are string type and as @PetSerAl responded in comments to my question: `movies.OrderBy(o => o.Genre == "Other").ThenBy(o => o.Genre)`

Comment: No problem, in future it would be beneficial to have lookup data like Genre to be in the database so that you can update data or in this example change view order without changing code.